# Proof By Induction Using Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm having a really hard time with this proof by induction:

Prove this formula by induction:  $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. Easy enough, right? Wrong. I have to do it using the following identities:

1. $\binom{2}{2} + \binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{2} + ... + \binom{n}{2} = \binom{n + 1}{3}$
2. $m^2 = 2\binom{m}{2} + m \text{ for } m \geq 2$

I've attempted this many times. I'm officially stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you attempted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, it doesn't appear you need induction with those identities. Here's my take on it (if this isn't what you're looking for, you ought to be able to write an inductive proof with the same steps):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = 1+\sum_{k=2}^n k^2 = 1+\sum_{k=2}^n \left(2 {k\choose 2} +k\right) = 1+\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-1\right)+2\sum_{k=2}^n {k\choose 2}.$$
The third equality follows from identity (2). I then pulled out the sum of the first $k$ integers using the well-known summation formula (the $-1$ is because we started at $k=2$). Ignoring the other terms for a moment, identity (1) gives us
$$\sum_{k=2}^n {k\choose 2} = {n+1\choose 3} = \frac{(n+1)!}{3!(n-2)!} = \frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6},$$
where I've applied the definition of "choose" and canceled out the common factors of the factorials. Substituting this into what we had before and finding a common denominator,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(n-1)}{6} = \frac{n(n+1)}{6}\left(3+2(n-1)\right) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$
I hope this helps!

Comment: That definitely helps a lot. My only concern is that I'd have to derive the summation formula. Or is that so well-established that I can take it as a given?

Comment: Ah. I assumed that since you were asked to prove the formula for the sum of squares you had already been given the proof for the sum of integers. The proof is a very simple one by induction; if you find add $n+1$ to $n(n+1)/2$ and find a common denominator, it pops right out. Alternatively, you can use Guass's pairing trick: write out $1+\dotsm+n$ and then $n+\dotsm + 1$ directly below it. Adding the top and bottom gives you $n$ copies of $(n+1)$. Now just divide be $2$ to account for doubling the sum.